# Regular expression to get specific pattern in snowflake

Tags: replace, substring, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a table with column data like below.

```
Column5 :
1) ["[\"( "ABC12345678", "ABC00123451","ABC00543211")\"]"]
2) ["[\"( ABC87654321\"]"]
```

I just need to clean this column and fetch it like below.

```
1) ABC12345678,ABC00123451,ABC00543211
2) ABC87654321
```

Currently I am using replace function repeatedly to clean the data

```
replace( replace (replace (replace(replace(replace(replace (Column5,'[',''),']',''),'',''),'"',''),'\'',''),')',''),'(','') as column5list
```

is there any regular expression which can I use for the purpose to clean the data.

Pattern remains same **ABC** followed by **8 digits**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nested REPLACE could be simplfiied with TRANSLATE:

```
SELECT Column5, TRANSLATE(Column5, $$[]"'()$$, '') AS result
FROM tab;
```

Sample data:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE tab AS
SELECT '["[\"( "ABC12345678", "ABC00123451","ABC00543211")\"]"]' AS column5;
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: This is awesome and simple one which I was looking for.

Comment: If I need to be specific for Pattern matching ABC followed by 8digits only. How can I do that